# How to copy string to clipboard in C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, clipboard

The `SetClipboardData` function requires a `HANDLE` reference; I'm having trouble converting my string for use in the function.

Here is my code:

```
char* output = "Test";
HLOCAL hMem =  LocalAlloc( LHND,1024);
char* cptr = (char*) LocalLock(hMem);
memcpy( cptr, output, 500 );
SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
LocalUnlock( hMem );
LocalFree( hMem );
CloseClipboard();
```

What am I doing wrong here and what's the proper way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Read the MSDN documentation for the [SetClipboardData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649051(VS.85).aspx) function. It appears you are missing a few steps and releasing the memory prematurely. First of all, you must call 
[OpenClipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649048(VS.85).aspx) before you can use SetClipboardData. Secondly, the system takes ownership of the memory passed to the clipboard and it must be unlocked. Also, the memory must be movable, which requires the GMEM_MOVEABLE flag as used with [GlobalAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366574(VS.85).aspx) (instead of LocalAlloc).

```
const char* output = "Test";
const size_t len = strlen(output) + 1;
HGLOBAL hMem =  GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), output, len);
GlobalUnlock(hMem);
OpenClipboard(0);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
CloseClipboard();
```

Comment: Works for me too... with two corrections: GMEM_MOVEABLE and no parameter passed in OpenClipboard();

Comment: Why copy the null-byte-terminattor too?

Comment: because SetClipboardData doesn't accept a length parameter, so it has to figure out where the end of the string is, when you use CF_TEXT.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168(v=vs.85).aspx for more info

Comment: Do I understand correctly, if the call to SetClipboardData succeeds system calls free(hMem) for you?

Comment: @Pyjong: Yes, except that it's `GlobalFree`.

Comment: Note that if you are copying a `wchar_t*` instead of a `char*`, use `CF_UNICODETEXT` instead of `CF_TEXT`.

Comment: Accoring to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboarddata), this answer is wrong. You must pass a valid `HWND` to `OpenClipboard`. Quote: "_If an application calls OpenClipboard with hwnd set to NULL, EmptyClipboard sets the clipboard owner to NULL; this causes SetClipboardData to fail_"

Comment: This doesn't work as @GetFree said.

Answer (score 18):

I wrote an open source command line tool to do this in Windows:

http://coffeeghost.net/2008/07/25/ccwdexe-copy-current-working-directory-command/

ccwd.exe copies the current working directory to the clipboard. It's handy when I'm several levels deep into a source repo and need to copy the path.

Here's the complete source:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <direct.h>

int main()
{
    LPWSTR cwdBuffer;

    // Get the current working directory:
    if( (cwdBuffer = _wgetcwd( NULL, 0 )) == NULL )
        return 1;

    DWORD len = wcslen(cwdBuffer);
    HGLOBAL hdst;
    LPWSTR dst;

    // Allocate string for cwd
    hdst = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_DDESHARE, (len + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
    dst = (LPWSTR)GlobalLock(hdst);
    memcpy(dst, cwdBuffer, len * sizeof(WCHAR));
    dst[len] = 0;
    GlobalUnlock(hdst);

    // Set clipboard data
    if (!OpenClipboard(NULL)) return GetLastError();
    EmptyClipboard();
    if (!SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hdst)) return GetLastError();
    CloseClipboard();

    free(cwdBuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes, it is simple to read, copy and it works right on, just what I was looking for. And the CF_UNICODETEXT is a horror not getting. CF_TEXT makes only one letter in normal US ASCII. 
The DWORD len should be a size_t len (not getting compiler complaints).

Comment: Your answer uses `GMEM_DDESHARE`.  I understand that your answer was written 11 years ago(!).  Modern docs say: `The following values are obsolete, but are provided for compatibility with 16-bit Windows. They are ignored. GMEM_DDESHARE...` from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalalloc

Comment: In case an error occurs, this code leaks both `hdst` and `cwdBuffer`.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [Microsoft's Documentation on using the clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649016(VS.85).aspx#_win32_Copying_Information_to_the_Clipboard). This requires that your using the WinAPI, but this shouldn't be a problem since your on Windows. Note that programming the Windows API is never simple unless you use a very high-level language.

Comment: Well,
I've already looked at that, and came up with the code which doesn't work.

Comment: You might just try copying the exact code and see if it works. Then you can go from there.