# Copy variable content to clipboard in C?

Tags: c, windows

Quick question: in this example code:

```
printf ("\nType in 1st address: ");
scanf ("%x", &address1);
address1 = (address1 - number1) * 2;
printf ("\nResult = %08X\n\n", address1);
```

How can I copy the contents of var **address1** onto the clipboard?

Comment: It depends on what platform you're running on.

Comment: What clipboard? (The C programming language has no clipboard.)

Comment: What kind of data does `address1` point at? What kind of data do you want to put on the clipboard?

Comment: I am using windows 7, `address1` should hold 4-byte hexadecimal number.

Comment: This Stack Overflow answer should help since it is Windows platform: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264137/how-to-copy-string-to-clipboard-in-c

Comment: I saw that post, but i don't know how to adapt it to my specific case. An example would be nice.

Comment: You don't know how to convert your value to a string?  Use sprintf.

Comment: @stakx: I am assuming he is referring to an operating system clipboard. What you Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v to. I found through my msdn access an article mentioning a _CLIPTEXT OS variable that can handle text. But it seems to only be accessible through FoxPro and later .Net. I'm definitely going to look into this some more.

Comment: Yes, that clipboard.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks everybody.

Comment: If you post your solution as an answer, it may be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

For the future readers, I decided to show an example how to do this - in Windows.

First format the data by using sprintf *(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)* if it's not already in correct format(const char*).

Then use the following Windows API to set the clipboard data.

- OpenClipBoard
- EmptyClipboard
- SetClipboardData
- CloseClipboard
- GetClipboardData

Here is a **very basic** example usage of those API's without any return/error value checking.

```
const char *Str = "Hello world";
const size_t strLen = lstrlenA(Str) + 1;
HGLOBAL hGlobal =  GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, strLen); //Memory must be moveable!
memcpy(GlobalLock(hGlobal), Str, strLen);
GlobalUnlock(hGlobal);
OpenClipboard(NULL);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hGlobal);
CloseClipboard();
```