# How to write a string to clipboard (Windows OS) with a Kotlin/Native application?

Tags: kotlin, clipboard, kotlin-native

I'm very new to Kotlin and making a command line .exe, on Windows using Kotlin/Native. The application should read from a text file and print on screen, line by line. When it reaches the last line of the file, it should put it in the clipboard.

`aFile.txt` looks something like this:

```
one
two
three
...
...
the last line
```

and the code `read.kt` (Kotlin/Native) I have so far is this:

```
import kotlinx.cinterop.*
import platform.posix.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    if (args.size != 1) {
        println("Usage: read.exe <file.txt>")
        return
    }

    val fileName = args[0]
    val file = fopen(fileName, "r")

    if (file == null) {
        perror("cannot open input file $fileName")
        return
    }

    try {
        memScoped {
            val bufferLength = 64 * 1024
            val buffer = allocArray<ByteVar>(bufferLength)

            do {
                val nextLine = fgets(buffer, bufferLength, file)?.toKString()
                if (nextLine == null || nextLine.isEmpty()) break
                print("${nextLine}")
            } while (true)

        }
    } finally {
        fclose(file)
    }

}
```

---

The code above prints each line on the screen, but how do I write the string `"the last line"` in the computer's clipboard? I'm looking for a native (not Java) solution if that's possible.

Thank you very much.

---

> **Update:**

Obviously, this is not the solution I was looking for, but I don't understand yet what are they talking about here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboarddata).

As a temporary fix, I was able to get what I needed using `system()`, `echo` and `clip` with code like this:

```
system("echo ${nextLine} | clip")
print("${nextLine}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, you can work with the Clipboard through WinAPI, as you can see [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/dataxchg/clipboard). The reference says, that you got to use functions from the `winuser.h` header. This header is included in `windows.h`, as far as I know, so it is in your `platform.windows.*` package. You can approve it by checking Kotlin/Native [repository files](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/platformLibs/src/platform/mingw/windows.def).

---

To clarify, what I meant, I wrote this small example of `platform.windows.*` usage. You can add this function to your code, and call it when you got to copy some string.

```
import platform.windows.*

fun toClipboard(lastLine:String?){
    val len = lastLine!!.length + 1
    val hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len.toULong())
    memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), lastLine.cstr, len.toULong())
    GlobalUnlock(hMem)
    val hwnd = HWND_TOP
    OpenClipboard(hwnd)
    EmptyClipboard()
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem)
    CloseClipboard()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I don't have enough knowledge to even understand it at this point. I was expecting Kotlin to have something similar to `println("string")` like `writeClipboard("string")` or something.

Comment: You can try to use something from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264137/how-to-copy-string-to-clipboard-in-c), it should be provided by the package I mentioned. Import `platform.windows.*` and play around a few. I think it can be easier than it looks, so don't give up so fast.

Comment: The sample code you added to your answer works, thanks. With all three imports `import kotlinx.cinterop.*`,  `import platform.posix.*` and `import platform.windows.*` I was able to compile.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection

fun setClipboard(s: String) {
    val selection = StringSelection(s)
    val clipboard: Clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().systemClipboard
    clipboard.setContents(selection, selection)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target other platforms in the future, you can have a look at Compose Multiplatform as well. It is multiplatform, so it would work on Mac, Android, iOS, web too.

Using it is easy:

```
@Composable
fun Widget(){
    val clipboard: ClipboardManager = LocalClipboardManager.current
    Row(modifier = Modifier.clickable {
        clipboard.setText(AnnotatedString("Some text here"))
    }) {
        Text(text = "Click me")
    }
}
```