Move Console Text to the Clipboard Programmatically in C or C++
Given that there is pre-existing text on a Windows 11 console, how can all of the text be copied to the clipboard using C or C++?
That is, I want to do the programmatic equivalent of dragging with a mouse across all of the text to select it and then pressing Ctrl-C so that it's captured into the clipboard.

C and C++ have no concept of the console window or how to interact with it. I'm not aware of any Win32 API to read a console's text that that is not user input, so short of using the Win32 SendInput() to manually simulate actual mouse and keyboard events being sent to the console window, I don't know of any other way to do what you want.

You asked this question yesterday.

You can use the console itself to highlight text with the mouse and copy it. My utility that copies the whole console buffer (including the scrolled part) to a file uses GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo() to establish the buffer etc followed by ReadConsoleOutputCharacter() to read the lot. If you want to copy it to the clipboard then you would need OpenClipboard() etc.

@gregspears  the OP wantS the "programmatic equivalent" of selecting and copying. So, I doubt they want the user to actually enter Ctrl-C manually. The program should take whatever text is already in the console and put it on the clipboard

@RemyLebeau -- thanks, you make sense.  I have code for this.  In your seasoned opinion, should I post solution or is this question destined to be closed by the community?  I've posted many solutions seconds and minutes before the community closed the OP's question -- this feels like another one coming...  thanks so much for your guidance.

@gregspears If you think you have a solution, feel free to post it.

@catnip perhaps because it looks like a request for code.

Here is the solution as requested.   This code is tested in MS Visual Studio and Windows OS 10 by me just now.
Please note that this is non-portable Windows code because OP has asked for a solution specifically related to the Windows OS and has tagged winapi.
This program prints a string to the console window, then captures/scrapes the text from the screen/console window via windows API ReadConsoleOutputCharacter().
The text data is then copied to the windows clipboard buffer.
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------

  copy_to_clipboard()

  Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1264179/3130521
  Credits: Judge Maygarden
*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
BOOL copy_to_clipboard(char *pBuff)
{
    size_t size = strlen(pBuff)+1;
    if(size > 1)
    {
        HGLOBAL hMem =  GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, size);
        memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), pBuff, size);
        GlobalUnlock(hMem);
        OpenClipboard(0);
        EmptyClipboard();
        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
        CloseClipboard();
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int main() 
{
    /* Get the handle to the console window*/
    HANDLE hConOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO CSBI;
    int win_w,win_h,size;
    char *tbuff;
    DWORD num_chars_read;
    COORD   dwReadCoord={0,0}; /* Read from screen top, left (0,0) */

    if(hConOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("STDOUT not available.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* Put some text to the screen */
    printf("This text should match the contents of the clipboard buffer on completion.\n");

    /* Get console window dims, potential text size, allocate buffer to that size */
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hConOut, &CSBI );
    win_w=CSBI.srWindow.Right - CSBI.srWindow.Left+1;
    win_h=CSBI.srWindow.Bottom - CSBI.srWindow.Top+1;
    size = win_w*win_h;
    tbuff = malloc(size+1);
    if(!tbuff)
    {
        printf("malloc() failed!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* Capture the text from the console window*/
    if(!ReadConsoleOutputCharacter( hConOut, tbuff, size,dwReadCoord, &num_chars_read))
    {
        free(tbuff);
        printf("ReadConsoleOutputCharacter() failed!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* Strip trailing whitepace (there should be a lot!)*/
    while(num_chars_read && tbuff[num_chars_read-1] == ' ')
        tbuff[--num_chars_read] = '\0';

    /* Copy text to the clipboard*/
    if(!copy_to_clipboard(tbuff))
    {
        free(tbuff);
        printf("copy_to_clipboard() failed!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    free(tbuff);  /* Always free() */

    /* Notify user done */
    printf("All done. Success. Open notepad and paste from clipboard.\n");
    _getch(); /* wait key press */

    return 0;
}


Your code works. Thank you very much. I had to change "tbuff = malloc(size+1);" to "tbuff = (char *)malloc(size+1);" But, otherwise, it's the solution I was looking for.

@BobPenoyer -- great news!  Very welcome and thank you for selecting my answer.  On adding the cast for malloc():  (char *)  -- yes, some compilers want that.  They shouldn't, but some do, lol.  It's a topic for another day.  Have a good one...

@gregspears "yes, some compilers want [the cast for malloc()]" - more accurately, every C compiler doesn't care about it, and every C++ compiler requires it. In C, void* is implicitly convertible to any other pointer type, but in C++ it is not.
